# Error with DeepFace library in Chaquopy Android Project

Tags: python, android, kotlin, chaquopy, deepface

I have been trying to run the following snippet of code for deepface for comparing two images containing a face.
Python code:
face_similarity.py

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
from deepface import DeepFace
import traceback
import tensorflow as tf
import vitis_quantizer

def convert_to_tflite(model, tflite_filename):
    # Convert the model to TFLite format
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(model)
    tflite_model = converter.convert()

    # Save the TFLite model to a file
    with open(tflite_filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(tflite_model)

def calculate_deepface_similarity(ekyc_base64, attendance_base64):
    if not ekyc_base64 or not attendance_base64:
        return "image is missing"

    try:
        ekyc_image = _decode_base64_image(ekyc_base64)
        attendance_image = _decode_base64_image(attendance_base64)

        if ekyc_image is None or attendance_image is None:
            return "invalid image data"

        # Ensure both images are in portrait orientation
        ekyc_image = _convert_to_portrait(ekyc_image)
        attendance_image = _convert_to_portrait(attendance_image)

        ekyc_image_np = np.array(ekyc_image)
        attendance_image_np = np.array(attendance_image)

        # Convert BGR to RGB (DeepFace requires RGB images)
        ekyc_image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(ekyc_image_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        attendance_image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(attendance_image_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # Perform face recognition using Facenet512 model
        result = DeepFace.verify(ekyc_image_rgb, attendance_image_rgb, model_name='Facenet512')

        # Check the structure of the result variable
        print("Result:", result)

        similarity_percentage = (1 - result["distance"]) * 100
        return similarity_percentage
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error processing images:", e)
        return str(traceback.format_exc())

def _decode_base64_image(base64_string):
    try:
        image_data = base64.b64decode(base64_string)
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_data))
        return image
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error decoding base64 image:", e)
        return None

def _convert_to_portrait(image):
    width, height = image.size
    if width < height:
        return image
    else:
        return image.transpose(Image.ROTATE_90)

def encode_image_to_base64(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, "rb") as image_file:
            # Read the image file in binary mode
            image_binary = image_file.read()

            # Encode the binary data to base64
            encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_binary).decode("utf-8")

            return encoded_string
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error encoding image: {e}")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example usage
    ekyc_base64 = encode_image_to_base64("Screenshot 2023-11-26 220725.png")
    attendance_base64 = encode_image_to_base64("Screenshot 2023-11-26 220806.png")

    similarity_percentage = calculate_deepface_similarity(ekyc_base64, attendance_base64)
    print("Similarity Percentage:", similarity_percentage)
```

However, I'm facing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/app/face_similarity.py", line 36, in calculate_deepface_similarity
        result = DeepFace.verify(ekyc_image_rgb, attendance_image_rgb, model_name='Facenet512')
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/deepface/DeepFace.py", line 169, in verify
        img1_embedding_obj = represent(
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/deepface/DeepFace.py", line 639, in represent
        model = build_model(model_name)
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/deepface/DeepFace.py", line 80, in build_model
        model = model()
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/deepface/basemodels/Facenet512.py", line 11, in loadModel
        model = Facenet.InceptionResNetV2(dimension=512)
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/deepface/basemodels/Facenet.py", line 49, in InceptionResNetV2
        inputs = Input(shape=(160, 160, 3))
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 270, in Input
        input_layer = InputLayer(**input_layer_config)
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 122, in _init_
        input_tensor = backend.placeholder(
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 1054, in placeholder
        x = array_ops.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2718, in placeholder
        return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6031, in placeholder
        _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 740, in _apply_op_helper
        op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 593, in _create_op_internal
        return super(FuncGraph, self)._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3307, in _create_op_internal
        node_def = _NodeDef(op_type, name, attrs)
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1569, in _NodeDef
        node_def.attr[k].CopyFrom(v)
    File "/data/data/rural.ekyc/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/requirements/google/protobuf/internal/containers.py", line 70, in _getitem_
        return self._values[key]
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

My build.gradle:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

    id 'com.chaquo.python'
}

android {
    namespace 'rural.ekyc'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "rural.ekyc"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        python{

            pip {
                install "deepface==0.0.79"
                install "numpy"
                install "opencv-python"

            }
            buildPython "/usr/local/bin/python3"

        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
        sourceSets{
            main{
                python.srcDir "src/main/python"
            }
        }


    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            def date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yy").format(new Date())
            outputFileName = "eKYC_APP_${date}_${variant.buildType.name}_${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    /* debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }*/

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding false
        viewBinding true
    }


}

dependencies {

    //Androidx
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    //Google
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'

    //Intuitx
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0"

    //lifecycle
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.6.1'

    //Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'

    //Dragger Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.12.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.2'

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2"

    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2"


    implementation 'io.github.rupinderjeet:kprogresshud:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.6'
    implementation 'com.github.chivorns:smartmaterialspinner:1.5.0'


    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.15.1'
    implementation ('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7') {
        exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull'
    }

    implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk16', version: '1.45'
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.crypto', name: 'jsr105-api', version: '1.0.1'
    implementation (group: 'org.apache.santuario', name: 'xmlsec', version: '2.0.3') {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.woodstox"
    }
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.stream', name: 'stax-api', version: '1.0-2'

    implementation 'com.alimuzaffar.lib:pinentryedittext:2.0.6'

    //bio-metric verification
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0'

    //    rootbeer
    implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.1.0'


}
```

The pip freeze > requirements.txt output for my Windows virtual environment running in Python 3.10.9 is the following

```
absl-py==2.0.0
astunparse==1.6.3
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
blinker==1.7.0
cachetools==5.3.2
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
deepface==0.0.79
filelock==3.13.1
fire==0.5.0
Flask==3.0.0
flatbuffers==23.5.26
gast==0.5.4
gdown==4.7.1
google-auth==2.23.4
google-auth-oauthlib==1.0.0
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.59.2
gunicorn==21.2.0
h5py==3.10.0
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
keras==2.14.0
libclang==16.0.6
Markdown==3.5.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
ml-dtypes==0.2.0
mtcnn==0.1.1
numpy==1.26.2
oauthlib==3.2.2
opencv-python==4.8.1.78
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==23.2
pandas==2.1.3
Pillow==10.1.0
protobuf==4.25.0
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3.post1
requests==2.31.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
retina-face==0.0.13
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.5
tensorboard==2.14.1
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.2
tensorflow==2.14.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.14.0
tensorflow-intel==2.14.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.31.0
termcolor==2.3.0
tqdm==4.66.1
typing_extensions==4.8.0
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.1.0
Werkzeug==3.0.1
wrapt==1.14.1
```

Android Studio version: Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2

Gradle version:  8.1.2

DeepFace version: 0.0.79

Chaquopy version: 14.0.2

The dependencies I have installed deepface, numpy and opencv-python.
Also, is there a possibility of running commands to check the python versions running so as to duplicate that in a virtual environment on local system. The code for face_similarity.py works fine on my local system and also in a Windows virtual environment.

If anyone has an idea of what I can do to fix this I would be glad if they helped me. Thanks.

I tried installing various combinations of libraries in my build.gradle file including deepface, open-cv-python, and often got the error that opencv-python version was not found too, and I'm not able to duplicate my python local environment onto Chaquopy Java Kotlin Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pip freeze` output from your Windows virtual environment is irrelevant, because Chaquopy creates a separate virtual environment using the Android packages from [its repository](https://chaquo.com/pypi-13.1/). The newest Tensorflow version in that repository is 2.1.0, which is incompatible with the current protobuf version, 4.25.

To work around this, add the following line to the `pip` block in your build.gradle file:

```
install "protobuf<4.25"
```